# Tomcat 7.0.47+ Websocket failover

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket

In our current generation web application we used session replication with tomcat clustering. (and a load balancer)
That way, we received an auto failover when a client sends an ajax request to a tomcat node that failed.

In our next generation web application, We would like to have a similar behavior,  only with websockets.

So my questions are :

1) Is it possible ?

2) Does it involve websocket-session replication? if so, are there any guides on how to do that?

Comment: indicate what you mean by `websocket-session`, is it the native websocket api session?, the JSR-356 `javax.websocket.Session`?, or the HttpSession object?

Comment: You know that `javax.websocket.Session` really cannot be replicated, right?  Its equivalent to `java.net.Socket` in meaning and purpose.

Comment: So how exactly do i get a cluster of websocket servers ? what happens if one node in the cluster fails? how do the JSR cope with failover?\

Comment: Reconnect with new `javax.websocket.Session` - there is no failover

Answer (score 1):

Websocket implementations that are part of a distributed container may need to migrate websocket sessions from one node to another in the case of a failover. Implementations are required to preserve developer data objects inserted into the websocket session if the data is marked java.io.Serializable. [WSC 2.1.2-4]